# Can not bring a background running vim to foreground?

Tags: vim, shell, zsh

If I have a vim running in the background, it seems that I can not bring it back to foreground. Do you have any idea, why?

[image: Bring a background running Vim back to foreground]

Comment: Works for me, various combinations of `^Z`, `bg`, and `fg`. Unable to reproduce.

Comment: Using `fg %4` is strange. You can just use `%4`. And what for do you run `bg` on already suspended vim?

Comment: @Zyx Yes, I know %4 will work as well. no particular reason to do that, just want to try whether a running background vim can be brought back or not.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either.

Comment: I also have this issue, but not with `zsh -f` and not with `zsh -f` after importing all options (i.e. by doing `source <(cat ~/.zshrc | grep setopt)` in a new shell obtained using `zsh -f`) and freezing most terminal options with `ttyctl -f`. I guess you have to bisect your configuration to find out what is causing the issue.

Comment: How did it get suspended? `<C-z>`?

Comment: @romainl Anyhow from within vim. Both `<C-z>` and `:susp` show similar behavior. I have not checked what will be done if I try to suspend by sending some signal.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either. I also get `[2]  + 6868 suspended (tty output)  vim` if I try to `bg` one vim. That sounds sensible, because I expect vim to redraw his window on a `CONT` signal. Only a blind shot: Have you tried another terminal emulator?

Answer (score 2):

I posted the same problem here on GitHub [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4174) and [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/666). And finally solved it, only to find the issue results from a [setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4642855/3552975) `:set shellcmdflag=-ic`. After I commented that out from .vimrc all aforementioned problems were solved.

Think twice before tell vim always to use an interactive shell because it will cause problems, as said here:

> Telling Vim to always use an interactive shell can create problems. A
>   better solution is to figure out what in your bash configuration sets
>   up aliases and how you can move that to a place that is loaded even in
>   non-interactive shells. For example, zshell only loads ~/.zshrc for
>   interactive shells, but it loads ~/.zshenv for all shells, so I moved
>   my alias setup there and it now works from within Vim. See man zsh (or
>   your shell's man pages) for more.

Please refer to the following questons:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/406330/zsh-doesnt-open-vim-or-gvim-until-terminal-is-closed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/commands-executed-from-vim-are-not-recognizing-bash-command-aliases